# zlib does not compress in standard zip format

Tags: python, compression, zlib

I am using python zlib and I am doing the following:

1. Compress large strings in memory (`zlib.compress`)
2. Upload to S3
3. Download and read and decompress the data as string from S3 (`zlib.decompress`)

Everything is working fine but when I directly download files from S3 and try to open them with a standard zip program I get an error. I noticed that instead of PK, the begining of the file is:

```
xµ}ko$7’םחע¯¸?ְ)$“שo³¶w¯1k{`
```

I am flexible and dont mind switching from zlib to another package but it has to be pythonic (Heroku compatible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`zlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) compresses a file; it does not create a ZIP archive. For that, see [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: But how can I do that on strings ? I am trying to avoid files as much as possible

Comment: Well, `zipfile` works with file-like objects, so you could use StringIO.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about compressing just strings, then `zlib` is the way to go. A zip file is for storing a file or even a whole directory tree with files. It keeps file meta data. It can be (somehow) used for, but is not appropriate for storing just strings.

If your application is just about storing and retrieving compressed strings, there is no point in "directly downloading files from S3 and try to open them with a standard zip program". Why would you do this?

Edit:

S3 generally is for storing files, not strings. You say you want to store strings. Are you sure that S3 is the right service for you? Did you look at SimpleDB?

Consider you want to stick to S3 and would like to upload zipped strings. Your S3 client library most likely expects to receive a file-like object to read from. To solve this efficiently, store the zipped string in a Python `StringIO` object (in an in-memory file) and provide this in-memory file to your S3 client library for uploading it to S3.

For downloading do the same. Use Python. Also for debugging purposes. There is no point in trying to force a string into a zipfile. There will be more overhead (due to file metadata) than by using plain zlibbed strings.

Comment: Debug purposes. I like standard things that re readable by humans ;) . Besides - zips can be read without a hassle by any software or programming language.

Comment: What I need is actually S3 and not SimpleDB. Do you know what would be the overhead? Memory consumption? as stated in the original question, this is not a must but a nice to have easy to debug format that I think is better than a non standard (not as standard) of a format which has a price. Thanks fo rthe quick answers! StringIO sounds good to me

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to writing zip files just for debugging purposes, which is entirely the wrong format for your application, is to have a utility that can decompress zlib streams, which is entirely the right format for your application.  That utility is [`pigz`](http://zlib.net/pigz/) with the `-z` option.

Comment: https://github.com/eladkarako/pigz-2.3.3-fixed   - will compile on most OS using gcc, zlib dependency fixed here (even works on cygwin/windows)